# Product between a column vector and a row vector

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices

I know that matrices product is correct when the number of the columns of the first matrix is equal to the number of rows of the second matrix.

Why I can't do the product between a column vector and a row vector? For example:

$$\begin{bmatrix}1 \\ 2 \\ 3 \end{bmatrix} \, \begin{bmatrix}1 & 2 & 3\end{bmatrix}$$

Thank you so much.

Comment: Matrix multiplication is basically multiplying rows with columns, so the length of the rows of the first matrix need to be the same as the length of the columns of the second matrix. You can do that in this example.

Comment: you can do that, the result is $\begin{bmatrix}1&2&3\\2&4&6\\3&6&9\end{bmatrix}$, understanding the vector as matrices.

Comment: Thank you all for your answers.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

> I know that matrices product is correct when the number of the columns of the first matrix is equal to the number of rows of the second matrix.

I wouldn't say "is correct", it is only *defined* in this case. You can *invent* your own product or way of multiplication, but the *standard* product of matrices only works, as you say, when the number of columns of the first matrix matches the number of rows of the second. Multiplying column or row vectors are simply special cases of matrices in general, so that condition still applies.

In short: it's a consequence of the (usual) definition of the product of matrices.

> Why I can't do the product between a column vector and a row vector? For example:
>
> $$\begin{bmatrix}1 \\ 2 \\ 3 \end{bmatrix} \, \begin{bmatrix}1 & 2 & 3\end{bmatrix}$$

Your example however, satisfies the condition you mention: the first matrix has $1$ column and the second one has $1$ row, so their product *is defined*. Note that as a result, you expect a $3\times 3$-matrix.

In general, multiplying an $m \times n$-matrix with an $n \times p$-matrix, gives you an $m \times p$-matrix:
$$(\color{blue}{m} \times \color{red}{n}) \cdot (\color{red}{n} \times \color{purple}{p}) \to (\color{blue}{m} \times \color{purple}{p})$$

Comment: Hello @StackTD Wolfram Mathematica said me that: Tensors {{1},{2},{3}} and {1,2,3} have incompatible shapes.

Comment: I'm not familiar with the syntax, but there's no problem with the product in your example (I updated my answer).

Comment: Thank you very much @StackTD.

Comment: Just to add to this (a bit late), the "standard product of matrices" is chosen to provide some key behaviors which prove extremely useful, such as having the associative property.  It is easy to invent a new product, but more challenging to invent one with the same properties.

Answer (score 0):

Matrix/vector product $C=A\cdot B$ is well define when:

$A_{n\times k}$ and $B_{k\times m}$

thus

$$C_{n\times m}$$